# Resume loop after caught exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am catching an inputMismatchException in my main method and want my do-while loop to iterate again after the exception is caught.  I even coded an explicit continue statement but that didn't work.  How can I do so?

```
public class AddressBookApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddressBook abook = new AddressBook();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Address Book Application\n");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int menuNumber = 4;
    loop:
    do {
        abook.menu();

        try{
            menuNumber = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            if (menuNumber < 1 || menuNumber > 4){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu number\n");
            } else if (menuNumber == 1) {
                abook.printEntries();
            } else if (menuNumber == 2) {
                abook.addEntry();
            } else if (menuNumber == 3) {
                abook.removeEntry();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thanks!  Goodbye.");
                sc.close();
                return;
            }


        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
            sc.next();

            continue loop;
        }

    } while (menuNumber != 4);
    sc.close();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left `menuNumber` equal to 4, which is the termination condition of your loop.  Of course your loop will end.

Comment: Yep, you are right.  I put that there before I put in the try-catch in order to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: menuNumber is declared outside of the loop and then incremented by the call to sc.nextInt so it is (in theory) being incremented. The problem as I see and describe below is that an exception of a type other than what he is catching is being thrown.

Comment: Sorry, looks like he changed the code after your comment and before mine.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized menuNumber to 4, but do not change it in case of an exception. The loop does attempt to continue, but exits because the statement `menuNumber != 4` is false.

```
int menuNumber = 4;
loop:
do {
    abook.menu();

    try{
        menuNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if (menuNumber < 1 || menuNumber > 4){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu number\n");
        } else if (menuNumber == 1) {
            abook.printEntries();
        } else if (menuNumber == 2) {
            abook.addEntry();
        } else if (menuNumber == 3) {
            abook.removeEntry();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thanks!  Goodbye.");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }


    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
        sc.next();

        continue loop;
    }

} while (menuNumber != 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
    if (fatal(ime)) {
        throw ime;
    } else {
        // try again
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop doesn't continue because an exception of a type OTHER than InputMistmatchException is being thrown. Change the catch to:

```
catch (Exception e)
```

or at least add that all encompassing catch condition.

A better solution is to inspect exactly what exception is being thrown and why, and then fix the problem leading to the exception. Having an all encompassing catch with a continue statement could, in theory, lead to an infinite loop because menuNumber is not incremented.